# How to get lightweight-charts to draw session breaks

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

I'm able to use lightweight-charts to display price and volume just fine. When the data is for multiple days, I want the chart to also show session break vertical lines (like it does in TradingView app). I looked through the Chart Options and API documentation and cannot find how to draw session breaks. Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, while exactly speaking you can not draw a vertical line, but you can substitute that with a histogram series having a data item on each session start. That series should be configured to have 100% height and should be semi-transparent so the candle behind that is not hidden.

[image]

[image]

The code should look similar to this:

```
verticalSeries = chart.addHistogramSeries({
  priceScaleId: 'vertical',
  color: 'rgba(128, 128, 255, 0.25)',
  scaleMargins: { top: 0, bottom: 0 }      
})
verticalSeries.setData(opens.map(open => ({ time: open, value: 1 })))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked quite well. I had tried adding a second histogram earlier but was using priceFormat as 'volume' so it caused all volume bars to rise up too. This method of using 'priceScaleId' worked quite well.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this.  I'm having trouble getting it to display for me.        const verticalSeries = chart.addHistogramSeries({
  priceScaleId: 'vertical',
  color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)',
  scaleMargins: { top: 0, bottom: 0 },      
});
verticalSeries.setData(opens.map(open => ({ time: open, value: 24 })));  Also tried just the timestamp: verticalSeries.setData({ time: 1580286360, value: 24 },);  Any suggesions?   I'd love to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 3.8 it is not possible to draw vertical lines on the chart. There are a few feature requests for this on the issues page for the library so it is possible that this may be added as a new feature in an upcoming release.

Comment: Thank you for the response and including the version number.